# Any php file yields error message `“ea-php54” is not an EA4 SCL PHP`, but EasyApache3 is installed

Tags: php, easyapache-4

We have EasyApache3 installed on Apache (Bluehost is the service provider).

Overnight all our php files stopped working. Running a php file from the browser yields error message

`[an error occurred while processing this directive]`

Running any php file from the command line, including `php --version`, yields

`“ea-php54” is not an EA4 SCL PHP`

Which is an EasyApache4-related error message. PHP 5.4 is the correct installed version, though Bluehost recently made PHP 7.1 available. They claim they haven't touched our configuration.

EasyApache3 (which we don't actually use for custom configuration, for the most part - we use custom includes in the apache config files) is no longer supported, but we haven't upgraded to EasyApache4. So I don't know why we're seeing an EA4 error message, or why the server is referencing EA4 in an error message.

The two main questions:

- What would cause this behaviour to start?
- Should we just go ahead and install EasyApache4? Will that help or hinder?

I'm reluctant to start doing new installations and config changes on top of the error when we don't know what the existing issue is.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: On googling whatever "EasyApache3" is, I've found a blog entry by cPanel that mentions that this specific tool was deprecated long time ago and support has ended by Dec 31 last year. PHP 5.4 is out of support since summer 2015, which is nearly four years now. Why do you still insist on using such a horribly outdated system?

Comment: @NicoHaase - this is a legacy project that's being replaced, but the replacement is still in final development and the legacy needs to keep running until the replacement is ready to go. We're aware of the deprecation and versioning issues.